# How to get nested value from option that are in config.ini file using python

Tags: python, configparser

I'm newbie to python and was wondering how to iterate over the following option `key1` within `section1` below and print comma separated values.

here is the ini file

```
[section1]
key1 = value1, value2, value3 
key2 = value4, value5, value6
```

expected output,

```
value1
value2
```

I'm using ConfigParser (python 2.6.6), but had no luck so far!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your current code (and tell us what it is doing wrong)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> config.get('section1', 'key1')
'value1, value2, value3'
```

use `split` to get separated values:

```
>>> key1 = config.get('section1', 'key1').split(', ')
>>> key1
['value1', 'value2', 'value3']

>>> for v in key1:
...  print v
... 
value1
value2
value3
```